# How to Change BG Color of Dynamically Created Widget with On_Press and Save with Pickle? (Python with Kivy)

Tags: python, dynamic, widget, kivy

Goal:

1. Change background color of dynamically created widget with on-press.
2. Save this state with pickle such that when I open the program back up, the new color change is preserved

Note: You'll see in my code that I haven't made an attempt on saving the button bg color state to a file yet, as I'm still trying to get the on-press event to function.

I get the following error:

```
  File "C:/Users/phili/scrollablelabelexample.py", line 45, in create_button
    button_share.bind(on_press = self.update_buttons_departoverride(self))

TypeError: update_buttons_departoverride() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Python code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, ObjectProperty, NumericProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock
import pandas as pd
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class AnotherScreen(Screen):
    pass

class BackHomeWidget(Widget):
    pass

class Sequence(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass

class CleanScreen(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CleanScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation = "vertical"
        Clock.schedule_once(lambda *args:self.create_button(self.ids.box_share))

    def create_button(self, box_share):
        top_button_share = 1.1
        color = [.48,.72,.23,1]
        for i in range(len(parts)):
            top_button_share -= .4
            button_share = Button(background_normal = '', background_color = color, id = "part"+str(i+1),pos_hint={"x": 0, "top": top_button_share}, size_hint_y=None, height=60, text=str(i))
            button_share.bind(on_press = self.update_buttons_departoverride(self))
            box_share.add_widget(button_share)

    def update_buttons_departoverride(self):
        self.background_color = 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0

presentation = Builder.load_file("garagemainexample.kv")

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return presentation 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

Kv Code:

```
#: import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition

ScreenManagement:
    transition: FadeTransition()
    MainScreen:
    Sequence:

<BigButton@Button>:
    font_size: 40
    size_hint: 0.5, 0.15
    color: 0,1,0,1 

<SmallNavButton@Button>:    
    font_size: 32
    size: 125, 50    
    color: 0,1,0,1

<BackHomeWidget>:
    SmallNavButton:
        on_release: app.root.current = "main"
        text: "Home"
        pos: root.x, root.top - self.height

<MainScreen>:
    name: "main"
    FloatLayout:
        BigButton:
            on_release: app.root.current = "sequence"
            text: "Sequence"
            pos_hint: {"x":0.25, "top": 0.4} 

<CleanScreen>:
    ScrollView:
        GridLayout:
            id: box_share
            cols: 1
            size_hint_y: None
            size_hint_x: 0.5
            spacing: 5
            padding: 90
            height: self.minimum_height
            canvas:
                Color: 
                    rgb: 0, 0, 0
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size

<Sequence>:
    name: "sequence"
    CleanScreen:
        id: cleanscreen
    BackHomeWidget:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `button_share.bind (on_press = self.update_buttons_departoverride (self))` **you're calling the method**, so you're trying to bind `on_press` with `None` (`self.update_buttons_departoverride` return `None`). If you want to pass arguments, use `lambda` or [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
from functools import partial
button_share.bind(on_press=partial(self.update_buttons_departoverride, arg1,...))
```

However, if you need to pass only the button's reference, it is already passed automatically. You just have to do:

```
button_share.bind(on_press=self.update_buttons_departoverride)
```

and:

```
def update_buttons_departoverride(self, button):
```

To store the configuration of your widgets you can use [`Storage`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.storage.html). A simplified example using `DictStore`:

**main.py:**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.storage.dictstore import DictStore


class AnotherScreen(Screen):
    pass


class BackHomeWidget(Widget):
    pass


class Sequence(Screen):
    pass


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass


class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass


class CleanScreen(BoxLayout):
    box_share = ObjectProperty()
    config_file = DictStore('conf.dat')

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CleanScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation = "vertical"
        Clock.schedule_once(self.create_button)

    def create_button(self, *args):

        top_button_share = 1.1
        color = (.48, .72, .23, 1)
        for i in range(5):
            top_button_share -= .4
            id_ = "part" + str(i + 1)

            if self.config_file.exists(id_):
                btn_color = self.config_file[id_]["background_color"]
            else:
                self.config_file.put(id_, background_color=color)
                btn_color = color

            button_share = Button(background_normal='',
                                  background_color=btn_color,
                                  id=id_,
                                  pos_hint={"x": 0, "top": top_button_share},
                                  size_hint_y=None,
                                  height=60,
                                  text=str(i))
            button_share.bind(on_press=self.update_buttons_departoverride)
            self.box_share.add_widget(button_share)

    def update_buttons_departoverride(self, button):
        button.background_color = 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0
        self.config_file.put(button.id, background_color=(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0))

presentation = Builder.load_file("garagemainexample.kv")

class MainApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return presentation

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

**garagemainexample.kv:**

```
#: import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition

ScreenManagement:
    transition: FadeTransition()
    MainScreen:
    Sequence:

<BigButton@Button>:
    font_size: 40
    size_hint: 0.5, 0.15
    color: 0,1,0,1 

<SmallNavButton@Button>:    
    font_size: 32
    size: 125, 50    
    color: 0,1,0,1

<BackHomeWidget>:
    SmallNavButton:
        on_release: app.root.current = "main"
        text: "Home"
        pos: root.x, root.top - self.height

<MainScreen>:
    name: "main"
    FloatLayout:
        BigButton:
            on_release: app.root.current = "sequence"
            text: "Sequence"
            pos_hint: {"x":0.25, "top": 0.4} 

<CleanScreen>:
    box_share: box_share
    ScrollView:
        GridLayout:
            id: box_share
            cols: 1
            size_hint_y: None
            size_hint_x: 0.5
            spacing: 5
            padding: 90
            height: self.minimum_height
            canvas:
                Color: 
                    rgb: 0, 0, 0
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size

<Sequence>:
    name: "sequence"
    CleanScreen:
        id: cleanscreen
    BackHomeWidget:
```

Comment: Both the button color changing and saving work! This helps a lot. I also appreciate the edit of how I was using 'Clock.schedule_once'.. I had trouble before getting ids to load before class was initialized, and now see that I could have just referenced 'box_share' id further up the widget tree and then use 'self.' as a preface in my code. A lot cleaner looking.